# Getting undefined method for nil:NilClass when trying to acess an instance varible

Tags: ruby

I am trying to access an instance variable of a class in another class, but I get:

```
:in `lies_outside?': undefined method `x_coordinate' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is where I`m using the variable:

```
class Grid
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @current_Location = Point.new(0, 0)
    @temp_loaction = Point.new(0, 0)
  end

 def lies_outside?
    if @temp_location.x_coordinate < 0 || @temp_location.x_coordinate >= @size
      return false
    elsif @temp_location.y_coordinate < 0 || @temp_location.y_coordinate >= @size
      return false
    end
  end
```

And this is the class where the variable is:

```
class Point 
  attr_reader :x_coordinate
  attr_reader :y_coordinate

  def initialize (x, y) 
    @x_coordinate = x
    @y_coordinate = y
    @x = @y = 0
  end
```

I have omitted all other methods in those classes and all other classes because this is an assignment and I only need help with that problem.

Comment: It's important that your example code be at least syntactically correct. As is, Ruby can't even run it because you omitted the closing `end` statements for your classes. Part of writing a good question is that you must include "the shortest code necessary to reproduce it", "it" being the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining this var: `@temp_loaction = Point.new(0, 0)`

and then accessing it as `@temp_location` (Notice the typo)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message. It says that `NilClass` does not have a method `x_coordinate`. That means that the receiver of `x_coordinate`, `@temp_location`, is an instance of `NilClass`, which is `nil`. So you should ask, "why is `@temp_location` equal to `nil`?". Look where you last assigned a value to that variable. Bingo! Because of a misspelling, you never assigned a value to it. When a variable equals `nil`, but shouldn't, it's often because it was never initialized, for one reason or another.